# required capital, commodity and trade volume given monthly target

Tags: foreign-exchange, currency, day-trading, cryptocurrency, online-trading

I'm considering trading currencies or stock full time and would like to estimate required capital and required number of trades per day, given a monthly income of X US dollars after taxes.

I'd also appreciate any hints to what commodities might work to support this scenario.

Comment: I would start off by thinking about how long you are prepared to sit in front of the screen each day to place and monitor your trades if you want to do day trading. If you are going to spend all day in front of your screen, how will you earn money if you do not make any from trading? If you don't want to be in front of the screen all day maybe you could consider other forms of trading that are not trading, i.e. having a position opened for a couple of days to a couple of weeks. The very first thing you should do is to read about and develop an appropriate Trading Plan.

Comment: Choosing what to trade is secondary, first you should develop how you will be trading, and that will come about by developing your Trading Plan. If you don't have a Trading Plan, then don't bother trading with real money.

Answer (score 0):

Required capital?

- you need at least whatever your broker's minimum amount is to open an account.
- you  need the minimum margin requirement to support opening the trade
- you need some additional capital to buffer adverse market movement

There are no required number of trades per day.  You can make 1 trade or 100 trades a day.  You can spend 10 minutes in front of the computer or all day long.  Big Brother isn't watching you.

Your monthly income has nothing to do with your trading.  Now if that was meant to mean how much account capital and how many trades you have to make to make a  monthly income of X US dollars after taxes then that's unanswerable because your ability to trade successfully - if you have any -will determine that.

I'd suggest that you avoid any regular  trading until you have a Trading Plan that you have tested in real time on a Simulator.  That's not proof of concept but it will definitely eliminate all worthless schemes..